# Cox Proportional Hazards Model with Time-Dependent Covariate and Late Entries in SAS

Tags: cox-model, sas

I am trying to fit a model in SAS that allows for both late entries (i.e. left truncation) and a time*covariate interaction.  I can fit both separately:

Late entries:

```
proc phreg data=data;
class exposure;
model (start_time, end_time)*censoringvar(0) = exposure;
run;
```

Time-dependent covariate:

```
proc phreg data=data;
class exposure;
model time*censoringvar(0) = exposure exposuretime;
exposuretime = exposure*time;
run;
```

But I can't figure out how to do both at once, since in order to include the time-dependent covariate, I seem to need a single time variable (instead of using the separate start and end times).

Any advice would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think for the second part of your code i.e add an interaction term with time in your model, you assume your exposure will change (hazard ratio may or may not change) according to some function of time, usually log(t), you used t directly here.

For the counting process input and time varying variable you need to rearrange your data set to long format, i.e each subject may have serval records and you need to calculate your time varying exposure according to every $event$ time.

SAS has a very good example [here](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63347/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_phreg_sect050.htm)